# How to install postgis on Nitrous.io?

Tags: django, postgis, nitrousio

Our django project needs postgis installed, how do we do this on nitrous.io? If this isn't possible, is there a range of IP's so we can open one of our db servers to nitrous.io securely and host our db elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a production tier Heroku Postgres plan, [you can use PostGIS on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search#postgis). Also, [here are the steps to setup a Heroku Postgres database on your Nitrous.IO box](http://help.nitrous.io/postgres/).